# how to create a range of random decimal numbers between 0 and 1

Tags: python

how do I define decimal range between 0 to 1 in python? Range() function in python returns only int values. I have some variables in my code whose number varies from 0 to 1. I am confused on how do I put that in the code. Thank you

I would add more to my question. There is no step or any increment value that would generate the decimal values. I have to use a variable which could have a value from 0 to 1. It can be any value. But the program should know its boundary that it has a range from 0 to 1. I hope I made myself clear. Thank you

http://docs.python.org/library/random.html

Comment: You have to be more specific. From 0 to 1 could be between 0 and infinity values. What are the steps?

Comment: Thanks but there is no step. It could be any value between 0 and 1. I just have to a variable which would have values between 0 and 1.

Comment: @eryksun Yes I need a random range. I should have put the word random.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are looking for a list of random numbers between 0 and 1, I think you may have a good use of the `random` module

```
>>> import random
>>> [random.random() for _ in range(0, 10)]
[0.9445162222544106, 0.17063032908425135, 0.20110591438189673,
 0.8392299590767177, 0.2841838551284578, 0.48562600723583027,
 0.15468445000916797, 0.4314435745393854, 0.11913358976315869,
 0.6793348370697525]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
for i in range(100):
    i /= 100.0
    print i
```

Also, take a look at [decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
def float_range(start, end, increment):
    int_start = int(start / increment)
    int_end = int(end / increment)
    for i in range(int_start, int_end):
        yield i * increment
```

Comment: Thanks but there is no particular increment. It just a random value between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

This will output decimal number between `0` to `1` with step size `0.1`

```
import numpy as np
mylist = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
```

Comment: useful function!  but I think the op changed the question to specify that the entries need to be random whereas arange will make an ordered series.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like list comprehensions would be fairly useful here.

```
  mylist = [x / n for x in range(n)]
```

Something like that? My Python's rusty.

Comment: If you want a list of 0, then yes, it will work perfectly. Integer division ftl!

Comment: I think that, in recent versions of Python, this actually works fine. Don't you have to use a // b to get integer division? Please check on this, Wooble.

Comment: Yes, in python 3 the result will be coerced to float, although assuming the OP is using python 3 without a [python-3.x] tag might be a stretch...

Comment: True, although the integer division thing would be fairly obvious here and trivial to fix. Besides, is it really such a stretch to imagine people use the current version of Python?

Comment: I use the version 2.7 and yeah its integer division so everything is 0

Comment: Hah, goes to show you. Well, I'm sure you can figure out how to fix it.

Comment: As far as I know being just a beginner writing float in front of the variable will work. Is that how to do it. Sorry I have just started using python.

Comment: @Shivani: sort of, except you'll get [0.0, 0.10000000000000001, 0.20000000000000001, 0.29999999999999999, 0.40000000000000002, 0.5, 0.59999999999999998, 0.69999999999999996, 0.80000000000000004, 0.90000000000000002] because floats can't represent some decimals.

Comment: Well, apparently the OP does want a bunch of arbitrary numbers, so I bet this answer is ok...

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> [Decimal(x)/10 for x in xrange(11)]
[Decimal("0"), Decimal("0.1"), Decimal("0.2"), Decimal("0.3"), Decimal("0.4"), Decimal("0.5"), Decimal("0.6"), Decimal("0.7"), Decimal("0.8"), Decimal("0.9"), Decimal("1")]
```

Edit, given comment on Mark Random's answer:

If you really don't want a smoothly incrementing range, but rather a random number between 0 and 1, use `random.random()`.